# How do I find "Frum" Authors and their Novels on Amazon Kindle?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, jewish-books, books-generally, authorship, hasidic-story

I am a big reader.
Was only able to find around 30 novels in Amazon Kindle through searching by these 3 authors:

Ruth Benjamin,
Chaim Walder,
& Ruthie Pearlman.

Where do I get a full list of "Frum" authors?
Or a list of their books?

Comment: As I commented the first time round before the question was taken down, you should look on both the Artscroll and Feldheim websites for a good selection that will help you locate other authors. For example here - https://www.feldheim.com/contemporary-literature/novels.html on the left hand of the screen it filters novels by authors so you have a big list to work through.

Comment: Artscroll has the same here - https://www.artscroll.com/Categories/SHR.html

Comment: Worth checking out Nachman Seltzer - https://www.artscroll.com/Authors/Rabbi_Nachman_Seltzer.html

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Despair-Jewish-word-Yehuda-Cahn/dp/B0006EA1VI/ref=mp_s_a_1_12?dchild=1&keywords=Yehuda+Cahn&qid=1633924216&sr=8-12

Comment: @Dov Already tried around 20 authors and non offered their books on amazon kindle. Will try the other 100+ authors. 

Also what do you mean that the question was taken down?

Comment: I think it might have been closed and then reopened. Either that or my previous comments were deleted?

Comment: Wouldn't searching by publisher work? The list of "frum" publishers isn't that long